# Sencha ExtJS PropertyEditor grid cell color

Tags: javascript, string, extjs, colors

I have a PropertyEditor in ExtJS.

```
Ext.define('PropertyEditorGrid', {
   //...
   this.flexColumnGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {//...
          listeners:{
            propertychange: function (source, recordId, value,oldValue,eOpts){
               me.valueChange(me.id,recordId,value==null?null:value.toString(), oldValue==null?null:oldValue.toString());
            }
          }//...
   }
```

I want to use 'propertychange' function, if the value is not suitable then print the grid cell text in red color, otherwise print in black color. I tried to use http://skirtlesden.com/articles/styling-extjs-grid-cells, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: use afteredit in that get the column el add css to it

Comment: i added the following function:
edit: function(editor, e) {
              e.grid.cls = 'x-grid-wrong-value';  
                        console.log('afteredit');
             }
in the css : .x-grid-wrong-value{color: #f00}
i see the log message, but the text isnt red

Comment: get the td el from e. it will be in e.column add class to that or use validateEdit listener

Comment: i added the class:
edit : function(editor, e) {
              console.log(e.column.el);
              e.column.el.addCls('x-grid-wrong-value');
             }
but it's not work

Comment: try this solution it will help you http://jsfiddle.net/w8wjmj4L/2/

Comment: i get error message: Type Error.
When i add the class to e.column.el, i see lot of classes. There is a class, for example x-box-value. In x-box-value class there is a color attribute. Is it problem, i have two class wich have color attribute too?

Comment: Ext.get(e.row.getElementsByTagName('td')[e.colIdx]).addCls('x-grid-wrong-value');
thats work. thanks!

Comment: hope you can mark the question as answered

Comment: yes i want, but it's my first question, i dont know how :( can u tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
Ext.get(e.row.getElementsByTagName('td')[e.colIdx]).addCls('wrongclass');
```

in edit event

you can use `validateEdit`  to cancel the edit if necessary..